# Database error when using UserProperties

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a simple script which was meant to create a new folder and file in it, for any new user of the script. The id of the folder is saved in UserProperties.
But at some point while testing i got a message "Data storage error" while trying to look up the any Project Properties (using File->Project Properties). After that same errors occured in every other script i have.

Basically i can niether view nor edit any Properties at all. 
How do i get rid of it? Is there a way to clear userProperties? (first thing to do was to clear the cache of my browser but obviously Properties are not stored in there)
And what could be the reason of this problem?

```
Browser: Chrome 20.0.1132.47
OS: Windows 7
```

Comment: Please file bugs in the issue tracker, not stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue - [Issue 1519 on the Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1519). Please subscribe to it so that you are aware when a remedy is available

Comment: Thank you, just found it myself